# SetInterval messagebox update crashing page through overloading

Tags: javascript, ajax, setinterval

Hi i have a message box and users can place messages, i am using ajax to update the messages and using a setinterval to automatically update the message every 20 seconds.. However the code i am using overloads the page with interval calls. from the code below can anybody see where i have gone wrong and how i would ammend this so the intervals are in a single loop. thankyou

```
$(function(){


$(document).keypress(function() {
        clearInterval(running); 
    })

        var running = setInterval(function (){ 
        var varLISTID = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-LISTID");  
        var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-USERACCOUNTNAME");
        var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname="+ varUSERACCOUNTNAME;
        $('#infobox1').load(mylink);
           },20000); //10s
});
```

Comment: this code is confusing, how come `clearInterval` is aware of `running`? Possible fix is to put the `keypress` event after the calling `setInterval`.

Comment: because its in a loop $(document) the runner is known on keypress as the var is setup by kepress, but i should drop it below correct. setTimout has solved problem anyway. thanks

Comment: @HagaiWild when you create a function the way that `$(document).keypress(...)` was created, it will "look" for the `running` variable when the function is invoked, not when it is being created.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(document).keydown(function() {...})` instead. `.keypress` might have issues, as stated by the official documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function(){



                var running = setTimeout(function (){ 
                alert('up');
                var varLISTID = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-LISTID");  
                var varUSERACCOUNTNAME = document.getElementById('datacatch').getAttribute("data-variable-USERACCOUNTNAME");
                var mylink = "loadmessages.php?listID=" + varLISTID + "&useraccountname="+ varUSERACCOUNTNAME;
                $('#infobox1').load(mylink);
                   },20000);//10s


        $(document).keypress(function() {
                clearInterval(running); 
            })


    });
```

SetTimeout instead of setInterval has solved the problem.

Thank you.